# Can you keep a angular lazy loaded component "alive" after router navigate?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

In my application I am lazy loading a component. Is there a way to prevent the component from being destroyed after a router.navigate?

I suppose that it is by design that a component gets destroyed and ngOnDestroy is being called when displaying another component with router.navigate?

I want the lazy loaded component to stay alive after the router navigate so I can display it together with another component on the same page, that is being loaded after a router.navigate.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Consider making component that needs to stay visible not navigable but always present next to `<router-outlet>`. If it cannot be like that consider using **named router outlets**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think the component needs to be navigable because it should be lazy loaded (afaik this is only possible in combination with routing). What do you think is the advantage of named router outlets here? Do they allow me to have a different behavior than having the component destroyed after a router.navigate to something else?

Comment: Lazy loading outside routing was possible but it required lot's of setup if I remember correctly. As for named router outlets you can decide by routing setup what changes on navigation. See code and runtime logs of this fast fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-named-outlet-with-logs (no lazy lading there but it show principle)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. It seems like a complete oversight that you can't prevent a component from re-instantiating (and destroying any data it has acquired) when you navigate back to it.